# Generate a wordlist using John the Ripper

Tags: john-the-ripper

I want to generate wordlist with these rules: 8 characters, at least one uppercase letter, at least one lowercase letter, exactly two numbers. I've done a lot of google searching, and can't seem to understand how to do this. Can I get some directions on where to look or how to proceed?

Comment: Are you looking to generate passwords by modifying existing dictionary words, or are you looking to generate all possible passwords matching that pattern?  (That's going to be a very very large list.)

Answer (score 7):

crunch is a password generator that can do some of what you may be looking for.

```
crunch 8 8 -t ",@@@@@%%"
```

is a command that will generate a set of passwords that are exactly 8 characters long following the provided template:

```
, generates an upper case character
@ generates a lower case character
% generates a digit
```

You probably want to set various options to crunch to limit the output.  For example, a small test of only four characters, like this: `crunch 4 4 -t ",@%%"` generates 67600 words.

See `man crunch` for more details.